# OpenGL: Drawing multiply triangles without shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, render, opengl-compat

How can I draw triangles without shaders?
I have such function:

```
void GLRenderSystem::renderTriangleSoup(const std::vector<Vertex>& vertices)
{
    /????
}
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use shaders?

Comment: Because I was asked such a task at the university

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use shaders, then you've to create a compatibility profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context). With a compatibility profile you can use immediate mode [`glBegin` / `glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequences. You have to use one of the OpenGL [triangle primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) types. For instance:

```cpp
struct Vertex
{ 
    float x, y, z;
};
```

```cpp
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
for (auto &vertex : vertices)
{
    glVertex3f(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
}
glEnd();
```

---

Alternatively you use the fixed function attributes and define an array of vertex data. I this case you have to draw the triangles by [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml). For Instance:

```cpp
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices.data());
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

---

Anyway you've to specify a proper projection and model view matrix. See [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml). The matrices depend on the scale of the vertex coordinates. The current matrices are initialized by the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix). Hence, if you don't set the matrices, then vertex coordinates have to in normalized device space. NDC is a unique cube from the left, bottom, near of (-1, -1, -1) and a right, top, far of (1, 1, 1). The NDC coordinate system is a left handed system. In the projection on the viewport the x axis points to the right, the y axis point upwards and the z axis points into the view, hence the depth is defined by z.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me. I'll try to do this. (if I suddenly make mistakes in English, then I'm sorry, I'm not a native speaker of this language)

Comment: @Stepan_Radchenko I think I make a lot more mistakes than you.